# Magento 2: How to remove code from html?

Tags: magento2, overrides, html

I need remove from the page checkout this:
[image]

The code of this html is the next:

```
<div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping" data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + $parent.getCode()}"/>
    <label data-bind="i18n: 'iwdMy billing and shipping address are the same', attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + $parent.getCode()}"></label>
</div>

<!-- ko template: 'IWD_Opc/billing-address/details' --><!-- /ko -->
<fieldset class="fieldset" data-bind="visible: !isAddressDetailsVisible()">
    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address/list' --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
    <div class="iwd-buttons-for-update actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action action-update" type="button" data-bind="click: updateAddress">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="action action-cancel" type="button" data-bind="click: cancelAddressEdit">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Cancel'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The path:

> app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\IWD_Opc\web\template\billing-address.html

I need just remove the next line:

```
<div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
     <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping" data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + $parent.getCode()}"/>
     <label data-bind="i18n: 'iwdMy billing and shipping address are the same', attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + $parent.getCode()}"></label>
</div>
```

I have tried to erase it again and again but the change is not reproduced. If I delete the file it does not work so this is the file to edit...

Comment: When you delete those lines do you clear the cache? Is your site in development mode or production? Are you using symlinks or copy for the templates?

Comment: Can you flush cache and run static content deploy?

Comment: Yes all, deploy, cache, statics... and there is no file that replaces the html. Is of the porto theme